# i have a gridview autogenerated by the query.. i need to access the values in the gridview for further calculation in next gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
con.Open();
string str = DropDownList1.SelectedValue; 
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(@"
    select distinct
           a.DepotCode, a.CustWt, b.CustName,
           b.Lat_Degree, b.Lat_Minute, b.Lat_Second,
           b.Lon_Degree, b.Lon_Minute, b.Lon_Second
    from   tblDepotCustMapping a, tblCustomers b
    where  DepotCode='" + str + "' and a.CustCode=b.CustCode", con);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds);
GridView1.DataSource = ds;
GridView1.DataBind();

con.Close();
```

I want to use this gridview value to calculate.. how to access the values in the grid.. help me..

Answer (score 0):

It will be easier to access the values through the underlying DataSet rather than through the GridView. IE:

```
con.Open();
string str = DropDownList1.SelectedValue;
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("select distinct a.DepotCode,a.CustWt, b.CustName,b.Lat_Degree,b.Lat_Minute,b.Lat_Second,b.Lon_Degree,b.Lon_Minute,b.Lon_Second from tblDepotCustMapping a, tblCustomers b where DepotCode='" + str + "'and a.CustCode=b.CustCode", con);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds);
GridView1.DataSource = ds;
GridView1.DataBind();
con.Close();
```

You can access the actual data using the DataSet variable ds.

Then something like:

```
DataTable t = ds.Tables[0];

// Manipulate and calculate your data here. IE:
foreach(DataRow row in t.Rows)
{
    row["column_name"] = 'some calculated value or your manipulated value here';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways in your scenario but the simple answer is to loop on the datatable in your dataset (ds) after binding to GridView1 and then bind that table to other gridview

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to do the calculations with the data in the DataSet itself before you bind it to the GridView.

However, if you want to access the items in the grid you can use gridview RowDataBound event to do certain things after the server controls bind to the datasource.

If you have this GridView in your page:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="True"
              OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" />
```

You can put the event handler in your code-behind file. A `GridViewRowEventArgs` object is passed to the event-handling method, which allows you to access the properties of the row that raised the event.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
  if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
  {
    // Access and modify the cells of your GridView.
    e.Row.Cells[1].Text = "<i>" + e.Row.Cells[1].Text + "</i>";

    // Retrieve the underlying data item. 
    DataRowView rowView = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;

    // Retrieve the DepotCode value for the current row. 
    String depot = rowView["DepotCode"].ToString();
  }
}
```

See also: [GridView.RowDataBound Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx) documentation on MSDN.